# ASP.NET MapRoute with exact match constraint

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have mapped urls in my ASP.NET application as below:

```
        context.MapRoute(
            "Product_v1_DataExchange",
            "v1/xch",
            new { controller = "Data", action = "Exchange" });

        context.MapRoute(
            "Product_v1_Register",
            "v1/register",
            new { controller = "Registration", action = "Register" });
```

I want only following urls to work:

```
http://servername/v1/xch
http://servername/v1/register
```

But following urls are also working fine:

```
http://servername/v1/xch?test
http://servername/v1/register/?*e/
http://servername/v1//./register/./?*
```

How can I put constraint so that only defined static urls will be allowed?

Comment: What do you want to achieve for urls with query-string ? a 404 error, or a 302 redirect to the querty-stringless url ? (or matching another route ?)

Comment: Yes it should be 404 if urls are other than static urls mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

Create a new `RouteConstraint` like this:

```
public class ExactMatchConstraint : IRouteConstraint
{
    private readonly bool _caseSensitive;

    public ExactMatchConstraint(bool caseSensitive = false)
    {
        this._caseSensitive = caseSensitive;
    }

    public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        return 0 == String.Compare(route.Url.Trim('/'), httpContext.Request.RawUrl.Trim('/'), !this._caseSensitive);
    }
}
```

Then use it:

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        "Custom",
        "My/Custom",
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Custom" },
        new { exact = new ExactMatchConstraint(/*true for case-sensitive */) }
    );
```

Results:

```
/My/Custom (200 OK)
/My/Custom/ (200 OK)

/My/Custom/k (404 NOT FOUND)
/My/Custom/k/v (404 NOT FOUND)
/My/Custom/? (404 NOT FOUND)
/My/Custom/?k=v (404 NOT FOUND)
```